# How to create a language family?

Tags: language

I understand the basics of language creation, but I don't know how languages evolve or why. I know it has to do with politics, geography, and culture but I don't understand how those things come into play.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. While we are dedicated to building worlds, a sister SE community deals with constructed languages. You might have better luck there. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to find more about us.

Comment: Concur: this question should be exported to the constructed languages stack --- we'd love to take it on!

Comment: What's the worldbuilding context here ?  There's a big difference between wanting to understand how language develops because you're just interested in that and in having what we need on this site : a worldbuilding motivation.  Note that the way a worldbuilder creates a family of languages is going to be focused on end result, not real world process.

Comment: @L.Dutch, I'm with elemtilas, this should be exported.  It's too broad for WB, although AlexP did a fine job - but it should be noted that despite his fine job, it's a thimble compared to a descent answer on the subject.  It might even be too broad for [conlang.se].

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE user69079, glad you found us, do consider picking a unique name for yourself.  While creating a language family is a great worldbuilding question, you're basically asking us to tell you everything about language evolution because you haven't done any research.  Creating a language in fiction does require some understanding of how languages evolve, because that tells you lots about linguistic structure.  You might be able to save this question but it's going to be closed soon.  That's okay, because it just gives you time to work on it without answers coming in.

Comment: @JBH: The only important parts of my answer are the resources given in the beginning and the quotation from Meillet. The rest is just a starter to give the OP an idea of what he is asking...

Answer (score 7):

- Start with the Wikipedia article on [language change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_change), follow the links and consider the bibliography.
- Do read the Wikipedia article on [comparative linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative_linguistics) and [historical linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_linguistics). Remember that what you are trying to do is run the comparative method in reverse in order to project the future evolution of a language.

Some freely available books on the subject:

- Ferdinand de Saussure, [*Course in general linguistics*](https://archive.org/details/courseingenerall00saus), translated by Wade Basking, Philosophical Library, New York, 1959. This is (an English translation of the) book from whence modern linguistics began. Just remember that the French original was published in 1915. Highly recommended.
- Winfred P. Lehmann, [*Historical Linguistics*](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.136040), Oxford and IBH Publishing Co., third Indian reprint, 1955. This is an easy-going, semi-modern introduction to historical linguistics, very readable. Long live the Internet Archive.
- Hermann Paul, [*Principles of the history of language*](https://archive.org/details/cu31924026442586), Longmans, Green and Co., London, 1891. While this book predates a lot of modern concepts, it is still useful as a basic introduction to the principles of historical linguistics. Just remember that it was written well before the modern ideas of systemic structures and the [wave model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_model) of language change.
- If you read French, the Internet Archive has a copy of [Antoine Meillet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine_Meillet)'s excellent work [*Introduction à l'étude comparative des langues indo-européennes*](https://archive.org/details/introductionl00meil), Paris, 1908.

---

> *Dire qu'une langue est une transformation d'une langue plus ancienne, c'est dire que, entre les deux époques considérées, il y a toujours eu des sujets parlants qui se sont efforcés de parler d'une même manière, en employant une même prononciation, une même grammaire, un même vocabulaire. Mais il ne se trouve jamais deux sujets qui parlent exactement de même. Les enfants qui apprennent à parler n'arrivent pas à s'exprimer d'une manière identique à celle dont s'expriment les adultes qu'ils s'efforcent d'imiter : chaque génération introduit, sans le vouloir, des innovations. Quand enfin des sujets isolés ou toute une communauté en viennent à utiliser une langue nouvelle, distincte de celle qui avait été employée jusque-là, ces sujets ne parviennent qu'imparfaitement à parler comme les membres des groupes dont ils veulent reproduire le langage. Malgré l'effort soutenu que font les sujets parlants pour réaliser l'unité de langue à l'intérieur d'un même groupe social et pour ne pas introduire des changements dont l'effet est de rompre une unité de langue à peu près établie, il apparaît donc sans cesse des innovations dans la manière de parler. Au bout de quelques siècles, une même langue parlée d'une manière continue par des populations qui ont fait de leur mieux pour rester fidèles à l'usage ancien a donc nécessairement varié. Et si les populations qui présentent ces variations n'ont pas maintenu les liens sociaux qui les unissaient au temps oij il y avait entre elles unité de langue, les innovations diffèrent d'un groupe à l'autre ; il y a dès lors, au lieu d'une langue une, des idiomes divers, qui concordent à certains égards puisqu'ils sont la continuation d'une même langue, mais qui, au sentiment des sujets parlants, sont distincts.*
>
> To say that a language is a transformation of an older language means that, between the two epochs considered, there have always been speakers who have tried to speak in the same way, using a same pronunciation, the same grammar, the same vocabulary. But there are never two people that speak exactly the same. Children who learn to speak can not express themselves in the same way as the adults whom they try to imitate express themselves: each generation unintentionally introduces innovations. When finally isolated people or a whole community come to use a new language, distinct from that which they used until then, these people only partially manage to speak like the members of the groups whose language they want to reproduce. In spite of the sustained effort made by the speakers to achieve the unity of language within the same social group and not to introduce changes whose effect is to break an almost established unity of language, there are therefore constant innovations in the way of speaking. After a few centuries, the same language spoken in a continuous manner by people who have done their best to remain faithful to the ancient usage has therefore necessarily varied. And if the populations presenting these variations did not maintain the social bonds that united them at the time when there was unity of language between them, the innovations differ from one group to another; there are then, in place of one language, various idioms, which in certain respects agree, since they are the continuation of the same language, but which, as perceived by the speakers, are distinct.
>
> Antoine Meillet, [*Aperçu d'une histoire de la langue grecque*](https://archive.org/details/aperudunehisto00meil), Paris, Hachette, 1920.

Basically, languages evolve because (1) the chain of transmission between parents and children is not perfect, and the transission of languages to foreigners is *very* far from perfect; (2) humans are lazy, and they will seek to minimize the effort needed to communicate; (3) humans seek novelty, and they tend to replace worn-out patterns and words with new, more expressive patterns and words; and finally, (4) words follow things, and new things tend to come with their ready made words from a foreign language.

### 1. When people learn a language they learn it imperfectly

This is just how it is, and it applies both to children learning their mother tongue from their parents and to foreigners learning a new language.

People rarely learn a language perfectly, unless they have a professional interest. What people do is learn the minimum necessary to communicate in a language, to the limit of their communication requirements. Most people have quite limited communication requirements, and thus they will learn only a subset of the language; and, when they find themselves in need of more extended communication, they often resort to inventing novel means of expression, thus changing the usage.

Moreover, humans have a very large tolerance of imperfect language. One does not need to know English all that well to communicate in English, because the recipients of the messages quite often have the ability to work over mistakes.

This imperfect assimilation of language has three consequences, namely sound changes, grammatical changes and semantic changes.

- [**Sound changes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_change): The pronunciation of any language will change in time. This happens quite slowly, because children need to be able to communicate with their parents; but over centuries, it cannot be stopped.

  One of the earliest direct attestations of a sound change comes from the Roman grammarian Papirianus, who lived in the 5th century, and noticed that what was written *ti* and should have been pronounced `/ti/` was actually pronounced `/tsi/`.

  > *Iustitia* cum scribitur, tertia syllaba sic sonat quasi constet ex tribus litteris, *t*, *z*, *i*.
  >
  > [In the word] written *iustitia*, the third syllable sounds as if it had three letters, *t*, *z*, *i*.

  What's most interesting is that sound changes quite often result in splitting a language along geographical divisions, because people tend to speak more like people around them and less like people far away from them. This is one of the main phenomena which give rise to language families; and when tracing back the descent of a given language, historical linguists often give a list of sound changes at each step.

  For example, between Middle English and Early Modern English the [following sound changes occurred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English#Up_to_Shakespeare's_English) (the list is far from exhaustive):

  - The [Great English Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift), which made English vowels so much unlike the vowels of other European languages:
  - `/aː, ɛː, eː/` > `/ɛː, eː, iː/`, respectively;
  - `/ɔː, oː/` > `/oː, uː/`, respectively;
  - `/iː, uː/` > `/ai, au/`, respectively;
  - `/au/` > `/ɔː/` -- Note how these changes mean that `/ɔː, oː, au/` rotated in place, becoming respectively `/oː, au, ɔː/`.
  - `/y, ɛu, iu/` > `/iu/` > `/ju/`.
  - At the beginning of a word, `/ɡn/`, `/kn/` > `/n/`.
  - At the beginning of a word, `/wr/` > `/r/`.
  - Simplification of geminated consonants: CC > C (all double consonants become single).

  (In historical linguistics, > means *becomes*, and < means *comes from*.) (For an explanation of the notation, see [IPA for English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/English).)

  The thing about sound changes is that they are generally considered to occur with extreme regularity whenever they occur. For example, one of the sound changes from Latin to Romanian changed all `/ks/` and `/kt/` into `/ps/` and `/pt/`; thus, when a modern Romanian word has `/ks/` and `/kt/` in the same place as the corresponding Latin word we can be certain that it was not inherited from Latin but rather it was picked up later as a learned borrowing.

  But sometimes a language exhibits a very bewildering array of incomplete sound changes, and English is a prime example. What this usually means is that the language was assembled from a multitude of dialects, each with its own sound changes, which were diverging and on the brink of becoming separate languages. In the case of English, this reassembly occurred just at the end of the Middle English phase.

  To get started, look at sets of sound changes attested in the evolution of known languages; for example, [sound changes from Latin to the Romance languages](http://udel.edu/~dlarsen/ling203/Slides/History%20of%20Romance%20Languages.pdf), the [Great English Vowel Shift](http://udel.edu/~dlarsen/ling203/Slides/History%20of%20Romance%20Languages.pdf), the First [Germanic Consonant Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimm%27s_law) (also known as Grimm's law), the [Second German Consonant Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_German_consonant_shift) (which made German distinct from Dutch), the multi-stage [Slavic palatalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavic_palatalization), the split of the ancient [Proto-Indo-European](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language) language into [centum and satem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centum_and_satem_languages) languages, the [Ruki sound law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruki_sound_law) and so on.
- **Grammatical changes**: The grammar of a language changes even more slowly than its phonemic system, but change it does. Grammatical changes are sometimes induced by phonemic changes, which erase the distinction between grammatical forms.

  - Quite often, grammatical changes tend to drive a language away from complex [inflections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection) and towards making the language more [analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_language), thus simplifying its morphology at the cost of restricting word order. English is a prime example of this trend: Modern English morphology is extremely impoverished for an Indo-European language, having almost completely lost grammatical genders and having drastically simplified nominal declension and verbal conjugation; at the same time, in English word-order is of paramount importance, quite unlike other, more conservative languages where it has remained much more relaxed.
  - But sometimes the inverse process takes place, language change creating new [synthetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_language) forms from former analytic forms. See [grammaticalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammaticalization) for examples of how this may work.
- [**Semantic changes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change): Words do not have the same meaning in the mouths of children as in the mouths of their parents, and even less in the mouths of foreigners as in the mouths of native speakers. This happens because most people know only *some* of the meanings of a word; while meanings which are not in use become lost, other meanings are accrued by some mental process of analogy.

  Anecdote: At work we use English to communicate between a very wide variety of people from different countries. Recently I have noticed with surprise that more and more people have begun using the verb "to revert" with the meaning "to reply" (to an e-mail, for example).

  A well-known example of semantic change in English is the word "rape", which used to mean "abduction", "theft" or "robbery"; the current meaning is derived from the general idea of "taking smth. by force", with the effect that former meanings are no longer in use and need to be explained when the word is encounterd in older literature. Similarily, the word "gay" used to mean "lighthearted" or "happy"; the current meaning being very different.

### 2. Humans are lazy

People will invariably try to get by with the minimum effort required to put their message across. What this means for language change is that:

- People will slur or drop short unstressed vowels with dispiriting regularity. English, especially the American dialect, is a prime example -- all short unstressed vowels tend to be pronounced `/ə/` if they are pronounced at all. (For people like me who speak natively a Romance language it is maddenning to see native English speakers make spelling mistakes because they pronounce words like "effect" and "affect" in the same way.)

  We have a list of "bad" and "good" Latin words dating from the 3rd or 4th century CE, known as the [*Appendix Probi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appendix_Probi). Many of the "bad" forms show the dropping of short unstressed *i* and *u*:

  > vetulus non veclus, calida non calda, oculus non oclus, viridis non virdis, ...

  (What's funny is that the Romance languages almost invariably continue the "bad" forms, not the "good" forms.)
- People will do something to simplify the pronunciation of consonant clusters which they find awkward. We have seen how English reduced `/kn/` and `/gn/` at the beginning of a word to a simple `/n/`. Italian is a great example -- it made many Latin consonant clusters into geminates: *directus* became *dritto* "straight", "right", *damnum* became *danno* "damage", *lucta* became *lotta* "fight", etc.
- People will avoid learning a foreign language past the point where they can make themselves understood.

  As luck would have it, we have found a set of letters written in the 2nd century by [Claudius Terentianus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claudius_Terentianus), a Greek-speaking Egyptian who enlisted in the Roman armed forces and who corresponded, in *very* bad Latin, with his father, a retired former courier and government agent. The letters offer an unmediated glimpse of how Latin actually sounded in the mouth of one of the millions of people who learned it as a second language.

  The effect of minimal effort in learning a foreign language is probably at its strongest when people from different linguistic backgrounds have to find a common way to communicate. In extreme cases this can lead to the formation of a [pidgin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pidgin) which can then evolve into a [creole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creole_language); in less extreme cases, this can lead to the rapid evolution and diversification of a language: consider for example the family of Romance languages, descended from the minimal Latin spoken by the Gauls, the Iberians and the Dacians. It is very likely that a very large part of Latin grammar simply never existed in the language actually spoken by the majority of the inhabitants of the Empire. Ablative absolute? What's that?

In the history of English a corresponding process may have occurred during the period of extensive linguistic contact with speakers of Old Norse. [Some scholars believe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English_creole_hypothesis) that this intimate contact with speakers of a related but yet different language is responsible for the massive reduction of inflected forms in English morphology, because while the roots of the words were the same, the inflections were different and thus tended to be eliminated.

### 3. Humans seek novelty

Words which are used very frequently tend to become dull and lose their impact, and quite often tend to be replaced with new words, which provide for stronger effect. Sometimes the old word survives with a restricted or shifted meaning; for example, Old English *dēor* "animal" was replaced with *animal* (from Latin via French), but survives (Modern English *deer*) with a restricted meaning. Sometimes the replacement word is a diminutive, or other kind of derivative, but quite often it is [borrowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword) from another language.

Vocabulary is the most rapidly changing part of a language; it is so mutable that historical linguistics tends to mostly ignore it. New words are constantly brought into the language, old words are constantly forgotten, to the effect that a few centuries are enough to make old texts hard to understand fully.

### 4. Words follow things

One must never forget that language has to be a reflection of the material and spiritual reality. As the material and spiritual life evolves, language must by necessity evolve in order to be able to express new realities. Shakespeare may have spoken an early form of Modern English, but his vocabulary definitely did not include words such as telephone, telegraph, television, radio, radar, laser, caucus, coordinate, communism, capitalism, feminism, nylon, vitamin, protein, moccasin, tomahawk, and so on; and words such as monitor, cosmos, orbit, satellite, substance, integral had a very different meaning. Less than one hundred years ago, a mouse was a rodent and nothing else; a computer was person who performed computations; a program was a plan for something to be done; a file was a string, wire or other device for holding papers together; and a font was a (very heavy!) complete set of typographic [sorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_(typesetting)) of a particular face and size.

As the surrounding reality changes, new words come into the language and old and now useless words are forgotten. The new words come into the language either by changing, extending or specializing the meaning of existing words; or by making new words from old words by any means of derivation (compounds, prefixes, suffixes); by borrowing from another language; or by inventing new words from classical roots -- in European languages, usually from Greek and Latin roots, but from other classical languages elsewhere.

Sometimes this change is quite fast; consider for example the large set of words introduced into the Latin language by Cicero in his laudable efforts to translate Greek works of philosophy and ethics: to him we owe the words *appetite*, *comprehension*, *definition*, *difference*, *element*, *image*, *individual*, *induction*, *infinity*, *instance*, *moral*, *notion*, *property*, *quality*, *science*, *species*, *substance*, *vacuum* and many others.

Answer (score -1):

> How to create a language family?

You don't, societies, social interactions, and even individuals do this over largish periods of time. Languages are practical things, developed for the most part in complete disregard of literature and academia.

The best you can do is make a language up, and then mash it around a bit so you have dialects and voila, pretend it's a language family.

How it's been done in the past is a population has a language and expands it's sphere of influence widely and subsets of it's linguistic descendants evolve their version of the language differently depending on their interactions and needs, with a bit of pure chance thrown in..

Comment: *"The best you can do is make a language up, and then mash it around a bit so you have dialects and voila, pretend it's a language family":* this is most definitely not [the best one can do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_constructed_by_J._R._R._Tolkien).

Comment: @AlexP sure it is, not much point showing me Tolkeins stuff, those aren't real languages. They're linguistic constructs. A real language isn't an intellectual exercise, it's a social one. Something your own answer outlines very well.

Comment: Of course, [*ceci n'est pas une pipe*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images) and all that. But still, [*omnis ars imitatio naturae est*](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Seneca_the_Younger#Letter_LXV:_On_the_first_cause). One should strive for verisimilitude to the utmost of their ability.

Comment: @AlexP lost me... I'm still learning English, never mind French and Latin

Comment: That's why there are clickable hyperlinks... Basically, the first link goes to a famous painting of a pipe by René Magritte with the title *The Treachery of Images*; the painting includes the text "this is not a pipe" -- because it is a *picture* of a pipe. The second goes to well-known quote from Seneca the Philosopher: all art is an imitation of nature, showing the importance of verisimilitude. Yes, the imitation languages of Tolkien are not actual languages; but he strived to make them *look like* languages with a deep history and relationships. Some people find that deeply satisfying.

Comment: @AlexP thanks for the insights, question was about creating a 'language family' not a language though. So my answer is about that. Creating a language family out of nothing is a bit like the Chinese made razor I tried shaving with this morning. It looks like a razor, just doesn't cut hair very well.